# Spring reactor parallel flux is stuck

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, stream, project-reactor

I am using reactor to create an infinite flux,

once I make it parallel, the stream gets stuck after the first passed value, can't figure out why

```
    val source = source().parallel().runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
            .map(this::toUpperCase)
            .subscribe(sink())

    private fun sink() = SimpleSink<SimpleDaoModel>()

    private fun toUpperCase(simpleDaoModel: SimpleDaoModel) = simpleDaoModel.copy(stringValue = simpleDaoModel.stringValue.toUpperCase())

    private fun source() = Flux.create { sink: FluxSink<SimpleDaoModel> ->

        fun getNextAsync(): Job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            val task = customSimpleModelRepository.getNextTask()
            if (task != null) {
                logger.info("emitting next task")
                sink.next(task)
            } else {
                logger.info("No more tasks")
                Timer("nextTaskBackoff", false).schedule(1000) {
                    getNextAsync()
                }
            }
        }
        sink.onRequest { getNextAsync() }
    }

    class SimpleSink<T> : BaseSubscriber<T>() {
        public override fun hookOnSubscribe(subscription: Subscription) {
            println("Subscribed")
            request(1)
        }

        public override fun hookOnNext(value: T) {
            println(value)
            request(1)
        }
    }
```

If I remove the parallel operator, everything works like a charm.

Note: getNextTask is a **suspended** function